# How to create this ui with reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, user-experience

[How to create this ui with reactjs?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3xIJ.jpg)

Comment: Check out how to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Kindly add more details so that people can understand what exactly you need

Comment: You are asking us to create a project for you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use

> React Semantic UI

for your design. Its simple and easy to use.

Link: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab/